# RestEasy Mock unit test with CDI

Tags: java, web-services, junit4, resteasy, wildfly-9

I've a simple RestEasy WebServie which will take a dependency.

When I test by publishing into Wildfly server everything is working fine. But I tried to mock it using JUnit. But, it's throwing `null pointer exception` as the dependency isn't injected.

Following is the code which I've done. What is wrong I'm doing.

**WebService;**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
public class IlService {

    @Inject
    private il.helper.RequestData rData;

    @GET
    public Response postIds() {

        return Response.status( 200 ).type( MediaType.TEXT_HTML ).entity( rData.getRequestData().get( "logicalOperator" ).asText() ).build();
    }
}
```

**JUnit Test class:**

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.PropertyInjector;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Registry;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResourceFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import il.helper.RequestData;
import il.services.IlService;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class IlServiceTest {

    private Dispatcher      dispatcher;
    ResteasyProviderFactory resteasyProviderFactory;
    ResourceFactory         factory;
    InjectorFactory         injectorFactory;
    PropertyInjector        propertyInjector;

    @Before
    public void setUpResource() {

        dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        resteasyProviderFactory = dispatcher.getProviderFactory();
        injectorFactory = resteasyProviderFactory.getInjectorFactory();
        propertyInjector = injectorFactory.createPropertyInjector( IlService.class, resteasyProviderFactory );
        propertyInjector.inject( new RequestData() );
        resteasyProviderFactory.setInjectorFactory( injectorFactory );
        Registry registry = dispatcher.getRegistry();
        registry.addSingletonResource( new IlService() );
    }

    @Test
    public void IlServicePost() {

        try {
            MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.create( "get", "" );
            MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

            dispatcher.invoke( request, response );

            Assert.assertEquals( 200, response.getStatus() );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```